# Scatterplot colors and legend based on label in R (plotly)

Tags: r, plotly

I'm building a `scatterplot` in R with the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  produto=c('P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P8','P9','P10')
  , categoria=c('A','B','C','A','B','A','B','C','A','C')
  , qtd_reviews=runif(10,10,50)
  , nota=runif(10,0,5)
  , flag_presente=c('Presente', 'Presente', 'Presente','Ausente', 'Ausente', 'MP','MP', 'Ausente', 'Presente', 'MP')
  , stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Then, I create one `dataframe` for each category (one for 'A', 'B', and 'C'), because I want to create a dropdown menu for each category.

I want to create legend for `flag_presente` ('Presente', 'Ausente', 'MP') with 3 colors, but when I add the parameters `color` and `colors` on `add_trace()` the filtering on `updatemenus` doesn't work.

Here's the full code:

```
library("plotly")

df <- data.frame(
  produto=c('P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P8','P9','P10')
  , categoria=c('A','B','C','A','B','A','B','C','A','C')
  , qtd_reviews=runif(10,10,50)
  , nota=runif(10,0,5)
  , flag_presente=c('Presente', 'Presente', 'Presente','Ausente', 'Ausente', 'MP','MP', 'Ausente', 'Presente', 'MP')
  , stringsAsFactors = F
)

unq_categorias <- unique(df$categoria)
for (ctg in unq_categorias) {
  assign(
    paste0("df_", ctg),
    subset(df, categoria==ctg)
  )
}


# Retorna o número maximo de reviews
max_rev <- max(df$qtd_reviews) + 1


######
# Gráfico
p <- plot_ly() %>%

  add_trace(data = df, y = ~nota, x = ~qtd_reviews, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', hoverinfo = 'text',
            text = ~paste('Produto: ', produto,
                          '</br>Categoria: ', categoria,
                          '</br>Qtd Avaliações: ', round(qtd_reviews, 1),
                          '</br>Nota Média: ', round(nota, 1))) %>%

  add_trace(data = df_A, y = ~nota, x = ~qtd_reviews, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', hoverinfo = 'text',
            text = ~paste('Produto: ', produto,
                          '</br>Categoria: ', categoria,
                          '</br>Qtd Avaliações: ', round(qtd_reviews, 1),
                          '</br>Nota Média: ', round(nota, 1)),
            visible = F) %>%

  add_trace(data = df_B, y = ~nota, x = ~qtd_reviews, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', hoverinfo = 'text',
            text = ~paste('Produto: ', produto,
                          '</br>Categoria: ', categoria,
                          '</br>Qtd Avaliações: ', round(qtd_reviews, 1),
                          '</br>Nota Média: ', round(nota, 1)),
            visible = F) %>%

  add_trace(data = df_C, y = ~nota, x = ~qtd_reviews, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', hoverinfo = 'text',
            text = ~paste('Produto: ', produto,
                          '</br>Categoria: ', categoria,
                          '</br>Qtd Avaliações: ', round(qtd_reviews, 1),
                          '</br>Nota Média: ', round(nota, 1)),
            visible = F) %>%



  layout(
    title = 'Título',

    # Legend
    legend = list(
      x = 0.6, y = 1.1,
      bordercolor = "#000000",
      borderwidth = 1,
      orientation = 'h',
      font = list(
        family = "sans-serif",
        size = 12,
        color = "#000")
    ),

    # Axes
    yaxis = list(
      title='Nota Média',
      zeroline = T,
      rangemode = "tozero",
      autorange = F,
      range=list(0,5.1)
    ),

    xaxis = list(
      title='Quantidade de Avaliações',
      zeroline = T,
      rangemode = "tozero",
      autorange = F,
      range=list(0, max_rev)
    ),

    updatemenus = list(

      list(
        y = 0.8,
        buttons = list(

          # Todas categorias
          list(
            method = "restyle",
            args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
            label = "Todas"
          ),

          # Categoria A
          list(
            method = "restyle",
            args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
            label = "Categoria A"
          ),

          # Categoria B
          list(
            method = "restyle",
            args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
            label = "Categoria B"
          ),

          # Categoria C
          list(
            method = "restyle",
            args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
            label = "Categoria C"
          )

        )
      )
    )

  ) %>% config(displayModeBar = F)

ggplotly(p)
```

Its in portuguese but it isn't necessary for understanding the code.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got it (after [Maximilian Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2776376/maximilian-peters) answer), was adding 3 traces for each category.  Each trace represent on level of `flag_presente`.

And then, for each button we need a list of 9 `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

It goes like this:

```
library("plotly")

df <- data.frame(produto=c('P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P8','P9','P10'),
                 categoria=c('A','B','C','A','B','A','B','C','A','C'),
                 qtd_reviews=runif(10,10,50),
                 nota=runif(10,0,5),
                 flag_presente=c('P', 'P', 'P','A', 'A', 'MP','MP', 'A', 'P', 'MP'),
                 stringsAsFactors = F
)

p <- plot_ly()
for (i in unique(df$categoria)) {

  # P
  plot_df <- df[(df$categoria==i) & (df$flag_presente=='P'),]
  p <- add_trace(p, 
                 data = plot_df, 
                 y = ~nota, 
                 x = ~qtd_reviews, 
                 type = 'scatter', 
                 mode = 'markers',
                 marker = list(color = "red"))

  # A
  plot_df <- df[(df$categoria==i) & (df$flag_presente=='A'),]
  p <- add_trace(p, 
                 data = plot_df, 
                 y = ~nota, 
                 x = ~qtd_reviews, 
                 type = 'scatter', 
                 mode = 'markers',
                 marker = list(color = "green"))

  # MP
  plot_df <- df[(df$categoria==i) & (df$flag_presente=='MP'),]
  p <- add_trace(p, 
                 data = plot_df, 
                 y = ~nota, 
                 x = ~qtd_reviews, 
                 type = 'scatter', 
                 mode = 'markers',
                 marker = list(color = "blue"))
}


p <- layout(p, showlegend = F,

            updatemenus = list(
              list(
                y = 0.8,
                buttons = list(
                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)),
                    label = "All"
                  ),

                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "Category A"
                  ),

                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "Category B"
                  ),

                  list(
                    method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)),
                    label = "Category C"
                  )
                )
              )
            )
)

p
```

We also need to notice that the legend is based on each trace, so it is better to hide.

Answer (score 1):

You simplify the whole code by adding each `categoria` in a loop. You then get the legend for "free".

```
p <- plot_ly()
for (i in unique(df$categoria)) {
  p <- add_trace(p, 
                 data = df[df$categoria==i,], 
                 y = ~nota, 
                 x = ~qtd_reviews, 
                 type = 'scatter', 
                 mode = 'markers')
}
```

This also simplifies your `updatemenus`.

[image]

**Complete, reduced code**

```
library("plotly")

df <- data.frame(produto=c('P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6','P7','P8','P9','P10'),
                 categoria=c('A','B','C','A','B','A','B','C','A','C'),
                 qtd_reviews=runif(10,10,50),
                 nota=runif(10,0,5),
                 stringsAsFactors = F
)

p <- plot_ly()
for (i in unique(df$categoria)) {
  p <- add_trace(p, 
                 data = df[df$categoria==i,], 
                 y = ~nota, 
                 x = ~qtd_reviews, 
                 type = 'scatter', 
                 mode = 'markers')
}


p <- layout(p, 
  updatemenus = list(
    list(
      y = 0.8,
      buttons = list(
        list(
          method = "restyle",
          args = list("visible", list(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)),
          label = "All"
        ),

        list(
          method = "restyle",
          args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
          label = "Category A"
        ),

        list(
          method = "restyle",
          args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
          label = "Category B"
        ),

        list(
          method = "restyle",
          args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
          label = "Category C"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

p
```

Comment: I got confused, but this is not what I want. I want the legend to be based on the `flag_presente`. I sorry if the question is confusing, I'll try to edit to simplify it.